# what is "Right click" keyboard shortcut in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, shortcut, right-click

what is "Right click" keyboard shortcut in Chrome

i want use macro to save picture on webpage and need to use "Right click" keyboard shortcut in Position the mouse cursor for open menu, but shift+f10 in Chrome does not work

Comment: Your best bet is a plugin, something like this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-right-click/hompjdfbfmmmgflfjdlnkohcplmboaeo/related?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

The menu button which is right below the R. Shift